# Using PHP recursively unzip a folder within a zipped folder?

Tags: php, recursion, unzip, extract, compression

I am trying to unzip a folder in PHP and do some stuff with the files. I have it working normally but I need to make this work for zipped folders inside of the zipped folder root.

So zipped1 might contain image1 and zipped2. I need to extract zipped2 as well. I am trying to do this by recursion as below. Obviously this is not the full code but the relevent bits.

```
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
function handle_zip($ZipHandler)
{
  while($zip_entry = zip_read($ZipHandler))
  {
   $ext = explode(".",zip_entry_name($zip_entry))[1];
   if($ext=="zip")
    handle_zip(zip_open($zip_entry));
  }
}
$ZipHandler = zip_open($tempFile);
handle_zip($ZipHandler);
zip_close($ZipHandler);
```

So the problem is that recursively calling the function needs to send the file as an argument, but zip_open seems to open uploaded files in their temp folder on the server - and this recursive arugment is not in that temp folder.

What can I do please?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but you could try

```
zip_entry_open($zip_entry,$entry);
handle_zip(zip_open($entry));
```

in the recursive call. [This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.zip-entry-open.php) is the relevant doc page.

Also you may want to get the last part of the exploded result instead of the second one, in case a file has multiple dots in its name, or none.

Comment: Thanks but no go. I get an error 1 when trying to read that in the while loop.